# python-docx string replace and documents merge

Tags: python, openxml, docx, python-docx

My goal is to create a docx document joining together several templates (docx as well) while replacing strings in them. Al of this using python-docx.
I am already able to join the documents together, what I miss is how to replace some of their content.

I found how to access the XML content to be replaced, this way:

```
    doc = Document(self.tpldir + self.main_tpl)
    for element in doc.element:
        if (getattr(element, "xml", False)):
            content = element.xml
```

at this point, in content I have an "XmlString" that I don't know how to manipulate, and put back in element.xml.

Comment: ok I am studying and understanding something more. xml is a method, returning a XmlString, I thought I could treat it as an attribute but I can not. I will have to find a way to implement a new method to overwrite the data